# Call Activity from a view

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

I have a class called `TouchImageView extends ImageView` and I detect where the user clicks on it. If it is a interest point, I want to call a method on the `Detailed_Image_Activity` that will update a `WebView`. How can I achieve this?

I found some ideas about using observer and observables but I don't know how to do that. I found this solution [Equivalent of iOS NSNotificationCenter in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327200/equivalent-of-ios-nsnotificationcenter-in-android) but I can't make it work it

This is my code in the `TouchImageView` class...

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(isPointOfInterest) {
            //The code below is used to update the WebView
            //The task called below exists in the Detailed_Image_Activity
            DownloadHighlightBackground HighlightDownloaderTask = new DownloadHighlightBackground();
            HighlightDownloaderTask.execute(new String[] { arg1.toString() });
        }
}
```

Comment: This could potentially help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

You can get the activity from within the view, in this way..

```
((MyActivity)getContext()).method_name();
```

Comment: I think this would work but my method is actualy an async task class inside the Activity...
In Detailed_Image_Activity:

    private class DownloadHighlightBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

So this is the method I want to call.

Comment: This resolved my problem, actually.
I created a method to create the thread to update what I needed.
Thank you very very much (:

Answer (score 0):

To start up an activity you need access to the application's context and then you can call startActivity.

Comment: But the activity is already started and exists, this is the problem.
I just need to call a method of it. :/

Comment: Sounds like your not doing something correctly because your not suppose to just assume that Activities are running. A quick dirty fix would be to make the function a public static. If your not able todo then you need to open up an interface somehow. Sounds like you might be able to extend Application because your able to assume that's running. You could also save this data in a shared preference and access it throughout your program. Then you'll also be able to set listeners to be notified when it changes.