# Why does my Activity leak?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an Activity that has an IntentFilter and a BroadcastReceiver, and I register them in my `onCreate()`.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_RCV_MESSAGE);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
receiver = new MessageReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

But upon ending my app, Logcat says:

> 07-03 01:38:19.567: ERROR/ActivityThread(304): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.intentservicetest5.IntentServiceTest5Activity has leaked IntentReceiver com.intentservicetest5.IntentServiceTest5Activity$MessageReceiver@44efe8a8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

But I do have

```
public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Why is my Activity still leaking when I do call `unregisterReceiver()`?

Comment: What do you mean "upon ending your app".

Comment: @AlexLockwood I think he means "upon ending his app" d=

Comment: I was just wondering if he was calling `Process.killProcess()` or something... that's what it sounded like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), your app is killable any time after `onPause()` on most devices (any device with less than Android 3.0 / API level 12), and any time after `onStop()` on any device.  That means `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called.  The best place in an Activity to register and unregister for broadcasts, then, is `onResume()` and `onPause()`, respectively:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_RCV_MESSAGE);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new MessageReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Note that as @VipalShah pointed out, you were using the wrong signature for `onDestroy()`. This is why `unregisterReceiver()` wasn't being called.  Using `@Override` will help you catch this kind of problem.

Also note that the symmetry between `onPause()` and `onResume()` is intentional.  If you look at the Activity lifecycle article linked to above, you'll see that `onResume()` is called during the initial start-up, not just when resuming from pause.  So you only need to register for the broadcast here, not in `onCreate()`.

Finally, note that I used your code for simplicity.  In reality, you'll probably want to set up your IntentFilter and MessageReceiver in `onCreate()`, and then just call `registerReceiver()` in `onResume()`.

**Update:** One more important note.  As per [Implementing the lifecycle callbacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks):

> Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work.

Many people here were showing the call to `super.onWhatever()` at the end of the method rather than at the beginning.

Comment: @Darshan When using a FragmentActivity, there is nothing you can do to prevent leaking broadcast receivers.

Answer (score 1):

**onDestroy** is not always guaranteed to be called when an application exits.  You should try unregistering it **onStop** or **onPause**.

Also, make sure you call your Activity's super class methods in your overridden methods:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
```

Try it in `onPause()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this onDestroy()

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);

    super.onDestroy();
}
```